# Geopandas - Trying to get exact location on shapemap

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to place the location of these community centres on my shape map. Currently the only thing showing on my map is the different levels of income factors from an existing csv file which I have linked. But as I said, I would like to link in these locations which I have the lat/long for:

[Image of community centre csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLhr6.png)

Current code to display shapefile of my city.

```
# set a variable that will call whatever column we want to visualise on the map
variable = 'D2_Empl_rank'
# set the range for the choropleth
vmin, vmax = 0, 420
# create figure and axes for Matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20,10))
merged.plot(column=variable, cmap='Blues', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8')
merged.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(s=x.WARDNAME, xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center'),axis=1);
```

[Image of city I've trying to add the locations in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FSnD.png)

Comment: To increase chance for receiving answer, consider create https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve